# How to checked checkbox which is loaded thru ajax?

Tags: jquery, ajax, checkbox

This method does not work because checkbox is not in the DOM:

```
$('input[type=checkbox][name=rememberme]').prop('checked', true);
```

I don't know how to use .on() because I do not need to bind event:

```
$(elements).on( events [, selector] [, data] , handler );
```

**How to checked checkbox which is loaded thru ajax using jQuery?**

Comment: check it after it got loaded through ajax.!

Comment: add the script to the success handler of the ajax method which loads the content

Comment: @RajaprabhuAravindasamy I cannot do it, because I have not access to the code for ajax load.
My code is in one WordPress plugin and ajax load is in another separated WordPress plugin.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$( document ).ajaxComplete(function() {
  $('input[type=checkbox][name=rememberme]').prop('checked', true);
});
```

Try this:

Answer (score 1):

try doing like, on your ajax response, get the checkbox and set it to checked, like:

```
var cBox = $($.parseHTML(your_ajax_response_data)).filter("input[name='rememberme']");
cBox.prop('checked', true);
```